# How can I display multiple sessions in a web site in a list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When a user logs into the web site I am developing it the gets the session of the user by using this code:

```
protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["LoggedIn"] = UsernameTXT.Text;
 ....
```

Then I have a "Card" where it shows the total amount of "Online Users" which is set up in my `Global.asax` file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
    Session.Timeout = 8;
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

So to display the user that is logged in I have the following in my `OnlineUsers.aspx.cs` file:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"My Connection String");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT first_name, last_name, email, user_name FROM tbl_um_user WHERE user_name = '"+ Session["username"].ToString() + "'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ss");
        GridViewOnline.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"]; 
        GridViewOnline.DataBind();
    }
    .......
```

This works perfectly, but when another users logs in it then doesn't display that users information as per above.

I have had a look on various other post here on Stack Overflow and some suggest that you need to save the session in a database and retrieve from there?  I might be wrong but does it not create a new session every time a user logs in? So then surely I should be able to display it? And how do I save the sessions in a database?  (Sorry for all the questions :-) )

Any guidance, explanation or help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

**SAVING TO DATABASE**

```
Session["LoggedIn"] = UsernameTxt.Text;
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                      .ConnectionStrings["CONN"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_um_user SET IsLogged = @isLogged WHERE user_id_pk ='" + Session["LoggedIn"] + "'";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLogged", 1);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

**SESSION END**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
    Session.Timeout = 8;
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                      .ConnectionStrings["CONN"].ConnectionString;

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_um_user SET IsLogged = 0 WHERE user_id_pk ='" + Session["LoggedIn"] + "'";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLogged", 0);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a question how to you test if another user is logged? I mean to you use your browser and open a new tab and login with another user?

Comment: I use Chrome as my default the I use IE as my second browser to test.  It does show me then that there are 2 online then.  I use a different log in for IE

Comment: It will then display that users information when I go to OnlineUsers.aspx but not the first users information as well

Comment: So you are loggen in chrome and IE at the same time and it shows only 1 session?

Comment: No it shows 2 sessions then

Comment: You said 'I use a different log in for IE'. So i guess you logged out and logged in with a different user using IE. If that is the case then the result is correct. Session is per browser (it's shared across tabs). If you indeed have chrome open and IE and then log out and log in with a different user using IE then it correctly shows 2 sessions

Comment: Yes,  So what I do is I log in as "Admin" in Chrome the open IE and log in as "user" So the when I look at "Online Users" I see two session.  but when I look at Who is logged in (as per my code above) it only shows me the currently logged in user.  So the code I have to display all the users (sessions) will not work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
 SELECT first_name
      , last_name
      , email
      , user_name   
      FROM tbl_um_user 
      WHERE user_name = '"+ Session["username"].ToString() + "'", con);
```

So the problem is in the last line:

```
WHERE user_name = '"+ Session["user","name"].ToString() + "'"
```

This will simply get the username of the user who is viewing the page (aka the session user).

If you want to resolve this you have to either store in memory the username of the users that log in everytime. You can use object cache. The logic is that when a user logs in you store his name in memory and then query with all those names.

```
WHERE user_name IN ("+ string.join(",", Your_Memory.Usernames)+ ")"
```

It's a simple list that stores the usernames.

Another solution would be for you to store them in your database with a simple flag you must create a column `IsLogged BIT` where you update it with `1` when the user logs in and when the user logs out make it a `0`.

So you would query like this

```
WHERE IsLogged = 1
```

This eliminates the need for using in memory storing.

**EDIT:**

```
Session["LoggedIn"] = UsernameTxt.Text;
```

The error is because you try to compare your primary key which is an int with a string.

```
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_um_user SET IsLogged = @isLogged WHERE user_id_pk ='" + Session["UserId"] + "'";
```

Here you have to get the userid. If you dont have the user id then search by username(if it  is unique of course)

To update when session ends:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // your code
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_um_user SET IsLogged = 0 WHERE user_id_pk ='" + Session["UserId"] + "'";
}
```

Just query the database on session_end just like you did on log in.

Comment: So how would I go about saving this in a database? Do I use the same table I use for creating the users or is it a different table? I assume going the database route is more efficient than using memory storage.

Comment: Using in memory is always faster. The problem is how many users you are expecting. If you expect a lot of users then use the database. If not use the in-memory. About your first question you can simply use another column in the tbl_um_user table, no new table is needed.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly. In my tbl_um_user table I add a column named `IsLogged` then in my login.aspx.cs I add the session as 1 and then when the users logs out update the table to 0?  But now what happens if the users just closes the browser instead of loggin out? How do I update the table then.  Sorry again for all the questions, I am just trying to understand how this works

Comment: This is actually the session_end. So it will be updated when the timeout has passed. So generally you want to log him out when the session timeout (Session_End). Also notice the fact that the user has closed the browser doesn't mean much. He's still logged in for the system.

Comment: Even if you used an in memory solution you would still have to wait for when the session would end so you can define whether or not a user has closed the browser or was inactive. It's impossible to know if the user has closed the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I have many users that will Log in so saving to database would be better.  I have updated my Question with the code to update the table but getting error saying `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' admin ' to data type int`

Comment: Could you please assist.  I know now whta I need to to do to achieve my goal.  Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: Works perfectly now.  Just having trouble Updating the table when the session ends, not sure how to do that.

Comment: Must I ask a new question or will you be able to assist in updating the table when the session ends?

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the original question or if it is seen as a new topic?

Comment: Now I am a bit confused :-)  The code to update the table I put in `Login.aspx.cs` and the same in `logout.aspx.cs` *just changed the 1 to 0.  If I add that code in the `global.asax` I get an error saying that `namespace 'SQLconnection` could not be found`

Comment: `using System.Data.SqlClient;` Do you use this namespace on your global asax? You need to have it on session end so you will update the database when a users session will timeout. There are no guarantees that it will pass from logout page

Comment: Okay Thanks,  I think I  have done it now.  Could you please check if it is correct now?  I don't get any errors anymore.   Thanks again for all your help.  Much appreciated!!!!

Comment: @KeithKing yes it seems fine. You might wanna remove the update from logout. Since a user that logs out will call session_end. You will be making 2 calls to the database as such. If this helped please mark the question as answered.